# Bash script with create-file-user command in InteliJ

Tags: bash, shell

trying to create a bash script which creates user by command "create-file-user". But this command can only be entered in asadmin console, not i Git Bash, so here is my question how can i create a script that create user with "create-file-user" and how to configure it (which interpreter should i use). Thanks for any help.

Comment: On the other hand, how can i switch to asadmin mode in git bash, so i can execute "create-file-user"

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) and [Super User](https://superuser.com/) or [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/) would be better places for questions like this.